# Convergence almost uniformly implies convergence in $L_\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Show that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ almost uniformly then $f_n \rightarrow f $ in $L_\infty$.

I know that convergence in $L_\infty$ implies converge uniformly and hence almost surely but I have problems to show the converse, because I not see how construct sets of 0 measure such that in our complements the $|f_n(x)-f(x)|< \varepsilon$.

Any hint or help I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. $\chi_{(0,\frac  1 n)}$ is a counter-example.

Comment: $\chi_{(0,1/n)}$ converges to $0$ almost uniformly but not in $L_\infty$?

Comment: @Nick That is true.

Comment: Oh I see, then almost uniformly is true, but if the convergence is uniformly implies convergence in $L_\infty$ ?

Comment: Yes, uniform convergence implies convregence in $L_{\infty}$ @Nick

Comment: Thanks!! @geetha290krm